# How to make my Python module visible by Cython?

Tags: python, cython

I have typical Cython code (.pyx) with an exception that it needs to access the variable from Python module:

helloworld.pyx:

```
from hellotest import label

def say_hello():
    print('Hello world!' + label)
```

And hellotest.py

```
from helloworld import say_hello

label = 'some label'
say_hello()
```

When I try to compile it with usual python setup.py build_ext --inplace, I get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hellotest.py", line 1, in 
    from helloworld import say_hello
  File "helloworld.pyx", line 2, in init helloworld (helloworld.c:967)
    from hellotest import label
  File "/home/dusan/projects/temp/hellotest.py", line 1, in 
    from helloworld import say_hello
ImportError: cannot import name say_hello

However, when I just remove label dependency (the very first line in helloworld.pyx and label in print statemet), code compiles and runs fine.

Can someone please tell me, how to access other module from within pyx code?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the issue is specific to Cython.  The problem is that you have circular imports.

Comment: remember: circular references break the import chain when a module is indirectly reached (i.e. tried to import) by itself, and so it "cannot be imported". the exception message is not too helpful and, in many frameworks like django, it could also give you many headaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. I was not aware that importing only a part of a module will cause circular dependency. If I had 2 modules x and y whereas in both of them have: import y (in x), and import x (in y), that would cause such thing, obviously. But I thought that importing only a part of a module (from x import constant) will not cause that. I came as C++ dev, so is there something like forward declaration? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that you tried to `import` `hellotest` into `helloworld` and to import `helloworld` into `hellotest`. This is called a `circular import`, which means that the `dependency-graph`, where the `nodes` are the files to `import` and the `vertices` are the `import` statements, so, this `graph` has a circle, therefore it will never be a `forest`. This means that you need to read `hellotest` to be able to read `helloworld`, but you need to read `helloworld` to read `hellotest`. If you imagine something which tries to analyze the dependencies, then you will quickly realize that the circle creates an infinite loop. Try to not form circles with your import statements in the future and you will be safe against this kind of problem.

Comment: If this is something Python can't handle, then it's Python developers' fault. Other languages handle circular dependencies with no problem whatsoever so why can't Python?

Comment: @RestInPeace solving the problem of circular dependency is working on a feature. Lacking a feature is not necessarily the fault of the developers. It might be intentional to optimize dependency handling, or it might be considered less important than other features. Circular dependency is not only a pythonic problem, it is problematic in C as well, for example. However, from the UX point of view, it is definitely better to have this feature, but that's not the only point of view.